# Basic Question on the Maximum notation

Tags: notation

I seem to have a problem with the Maximum notation. I'm sorry if this was asked before. I googled my question before I posted it here.

So if we have $$\displaystyle\max_{ i \in I} {A_i  <  y}$$
Does this mean the maximum value of $i$ or the maximum value of $A_i$ with $i \in I$ for which the inequality holds?

Comment: The latter is correct

Comment: Thank you for your help @bounceback

Comment: Keep in mind that $I$ is an [index set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_set) and thus need not have any structure (order, etc.) beyond that of simply being a set (although in some cases it could have additional structure, but even then the answer to your question is your second interpretation).

Comment: Thank you @DaveL.Renfro

Comment: if you want the index (more precisely the set of indices) where $A_i$ is maximized, use [argmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max) instead of max.

Comment: Thank you @achille hui